# IPv6 ping6 Connect: Network is unreach

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have docker running on a Ubuntu Server host 16.04.4 (Kernel 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64). Since my ISP has DS-Lite, I tried to set up IPv6 for the docker machines and am afraid I messed up things in the process. My Ubuntu host has an IPv6 address, but I cannot ping6 any network outside my computer any more.

here are some outputs:

```
$ ping6 www.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable

$ ifconfig
br-ace19c478d5b Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 02:42:33:16:f2:fc  
          inet Adresse:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Maske:255.255.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::42:33ff:fe16:f2fc/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:37978 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:63257 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:18846932 (18.8 MB)  TX-Bytes:81121316 (81.1 MB)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 02:42:95:34:eb:84  
          inet Adresse:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Maske:255.255.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::42:95ff:fe34:eb84/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          inet6-Adresse: 2a02:aa11:b17e:c200::1/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::1/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:522471 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:518631 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:134742413 (134.7 MB)  TX-Bytes:88819056 (88.8 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 2c:76:8a:ab:d9:66  
          inet Adresse:172.16.0.5  Bcast:172.16.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::2e76:8aff:feab:d966/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          inet6-Adresse: 2a02:aa11:b17e:c200:2e76:8aff:feab:d966/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:31476 Fehler:0 Verloren:1 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:5325 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:13604115 (13.6 MB)  TX-Bytes:574695 (574.6 KB)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:1585 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:1585 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1 
          RX-Bytes:100247 (100.2 KB)  TX-Bytes:100247 (100.2 KB)

veth7d7ecbd Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse be:93:ec:a0:ed:27  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::bc93:ecff:fea0:ed27/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:522471 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:518638 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:142057007 (142.0 MB)  TX-Bytes:88819794 (88.8 MB)

vetha899ff0 Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse fa:26:0a:9d:e3:0e  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::f826:aff:fe9d:e30e/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:85575 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:102665 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:28698296 (28.6 MB)  TX-Bytes:112130930 (112.1 MB)

vethfd63595 Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 6e:d5:10:50:85:50  
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::6cd5:10ff:fe50:8550/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:39401 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:47644 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:31008876 (31.0 MB)  TX-Bytes:9328942 (9.3 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 1c:87:2c:b7:89:77  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.40  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: 2a02:aa11:b17e:c200:d25:5443:ae5b:4642/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: 2a02:aa11:b17e:c200:91b4:2fbf:2483:b239/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: 2a02:aa11:b17e:c200:8191:f603:8401:899f/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::1e87:2cff:feb7:8977/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          inet6-Adresse: 2a02:aa11:b17e:c200:1e87:2cff:feb7:8977/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:632380 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:1348265
          TX-Pakete:582737 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:195257043 (195.2 MB)  TX-Bytes:174592022 (174.5 MB)
          Interrupt:18 Basisadresse:0x8000

$ ip -6 route
2a02:aa11:b17e:c200::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 931862sec pref medium
2a02:aa11:b17e:c200::/64 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 931863sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev docker0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth7d7ecbd  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vetha899ff0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev br-ace19c478d5b  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vethfd63595  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium

$ ip -6 neigh
2a02:aa11:b17e:c200::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 931862sec pref medium
2a02:aa11:b17e:c200::/64 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 931863sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev docker0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth7d7ecbd  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vetha899ff0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev br-ace19c478d5b  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev vethfd63595  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
adrian@ubuntu-host:~$ ip -6 neigh
fe80::e769:89f3:23b0:873b dev wlp2s0 lladdr b8:27:eb:6c:90:fe STALE
fe80::4e02:b7f3:79d2:59c8 dev wlp2s0 lladdr b8:27:eb:39:c5:ab STALE
fe80::de0b:34ff:fe86:ed03 dev eth0 lladdr dc:0b:34:86:ed:03 STALE
fe80::42:acff:fe11:2 dev docker0 lladdr 02:42:ac:11:00:02 STALE
fe80::925c:44ff:fec3:e9df dev wlp2s0 lladdr 90:5c:44:c3:e9:df router STALE
fe80::5c00:79e:3970:20ae dev wlp2s0 lladdr 00:28:f8:d7:fc:b2 STALE
2a02:aa11:b17e:c200:0:242:ac11:2 dev docker0 lladdr 02:42:ac:11:00:02 STALE
fe80::de0b:34ff:fe86:ed03 dev wlp2s0 lladdr dc:0b:34:86:ed:03 STALE
fe80::e769:89f3:23b0:873b dev eth0 lladdr b8:27:eb:6c:90:fe STALE
2a02:aa11:b17e:c200:0:242:ac11:2 dev eth0  FAILED
fe80::4e02:b7f3:79d2:59c8 dev eth0 lladdr b8:27:eb:39:c5:ab STALE
fe80::925c:44ff:fec3:e9df dev eth0 lladdr 90:5c:44:c3:e9:df router STALE
fe80::5c00:79e:3970:20ae dev eth0 lladdr 00:28:f8:d7:fc:b2 STALE

$ ip6tables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

EDIT:

```
/etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
        wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.16.0.41
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 172.16.0.0
        broadcast 172.16.0.255
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

What is the issue with my IPv6 configuration?

Comment: Your default route has gone missing. What have you got in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nmcli dev show`? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHampton For my better understanding: where did you see, that the default route is missing?

Comment: There is no default route listed in `ip -6 route`.

Comment: I added the config file in my post..

@DavidFoerster I dont have nmcli/networkmanager installed on the host...

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Thank you for the hint... That was it! 

the command 

$ ip -6 route add default via fe80::925c:44ff:fec3:e9df dev wlp2s0

 did the trick...